# What exactly is java making when round the number 6.02E23?

Tags: java

I wanna know why do java print me that number `9223372036854775807` when I write that statement `System.out.print(Math.round(6.02e23)`. What exactly is java doing?

Comment: @Lino No overflow here. Double goes to `~1.7E308`. `6.02E23` is nothing (a mere 600 thousand billion billion :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.round()` returns a `long`. But your number overflows `Long`'s max value, which makes it return the maximum `long` value possible: 9223372036854775807

From [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-):

> If the argument is positive infinity **or any value greater than or
>   equal to the value of Long.MAX_VALUE, the result is equal to the value
>   of Long.MAX_VALUE**.

```
6.02e23        = 602000000000000000000000 
Long.MAX_VALUE =      9223372036854775807
```